# Compound Interest - Changing interest rates

Tags: finance

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q51VD.png)
[Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5yM2.png)

Hello, my problem involves compound interest specifically with changing interests. I tried doing the problem above by doing it in (2) and even tried putting it in a solver to do my calculations for me.

Not fully sure the method is correct either since the shortcut of calculating the interest's together was used instead of separately. I'm not too sure where I went wrong with how I did it and would like some help

Thank you for reading

Comment: You calculation is right if $\$15500$ is the future value. But it is the other way round. $\$15500$ is the present value. $\text{Future value}=15,500\cdot \left( 1+\frac{0.06}{12} \right)^{48}\cdot \left( 1+\frac{0.04}{12} \right)^{12}=20,494.89$

Comment: Ah I see the wording got me on what I assumed which was which. That's a load of. Thank you for answering! :D

Comment: You´re welcome, IncognitoBatman